# Proper Way To Display Error Message on Multi-Line Opportunity Product Page

Tags: opportunity, validation-rule, error-messages, opportunity-lineitem, dmlexception

So I am having some trouble displaying an error that happens on the Opportunity sObject.

Currently, there is a validation rule that works perfectly. However, this is usually only hit when I save an Opportunity Product.

The problem I am having is displaying a cleaner error message.

Currently, the best I can do is display the stack trace when an error occurs. I don't want that. I makes users flip out when they see it.

I tried putting my DML in a try/catch block and if it failed, but it gives me the following error:

> ... System.FinalException: SObject row does not allow errors: ...

Not the output I had in mind.

The following code below is executed during an after update event on the OpportunityLineItem sObject. I am hoping there is a way to update the error code to a simple message like 'Opps, my bad.' (obviously something more meaningful, but you get the idea).

```
public with sharing class M_OpportunityService 
{
    public void AssignOpportunityCorrectBrands(Set<Id> opportunityIds)
    {
        Map<Id, Set<String>> opportunityToBrandMap = new Map<Id, Set<String>>();

        for(OpportunityLineItem singleLineItem : [SELECT OpportunityId, Brand__c FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE OpportunityId IN :opportunityIds])
        {
            if(!opportunityToBrandMap.containsKey(singleLineItem.OpportunityId))
                opportunityToBrandMap.put(singleLineItem.OpportunityId, new Set<String>());
            opportunityToBrandMap.get(singleLineItem.OpportunityId).add(singleLineItem.Brand__c);
        }

        List<Opportunity> opportunitiesToBrand = [SELECT Id FROM Opportunity WHERE Id IN :opportunityIds];

        for(Opportunity singleOpportunity : opportunitiesToBrand)
            singleOpportunity.mkto71_Brand__c = String.join(new List<String>(opportunityToBrandMap.get(singleOpportunity.Id)), ';');

        try{ UPDATE opportunitiesToBrand; } 
        catch(Exception error)
        {
            if(!Trigger.isExecuting)
                ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Please choose the correct stage prior to saving.')); 
            else
                for(Opportunity singleOpportunity : opportunitiesToBrand)
                    singleOpportunity.addError('Please choose the correct stage prior to saving.');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is you are putting addError on the wrong object

You have to put the `addError(..)` on the relevant row in `Trigger.new`, not on `opportunitiesToBrand`.

So, you'll need something like this in your catch block

```
if(!Trigger.isExecuting)
    ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Please choose the correct stage prior to saving.')); 
else
   for(Opportunity singleOpportunity : opportunitiesToBrand)
      Trigger.newmap.get(singleOpportunity.Id).addError('Please choose the correct stage prior to saving.');
```